# Docker - Web browser cannot connect to a running web app container on server

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I have successfully built my web app image and ran a container on my server, which is an EC2 instance, with no error at all, but when I tried to access the web page it returned no connection, even though I accessed through the binded port of the host server. The build and run processes gave absolutely no error, either build error or connection error. I'm new to both Docker and AWS, so I'm not sure what could be the problem. Any help from you guys is really appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install dependencies, nothing wrong
RUN ...
COPY...
#

# exposed ports
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5100

CMD ...
```

Docker build

```
$ sudo docker built -t demo-app
```

Docker run command

```
$ sudo docker run -it -p 8080:5000 -p 808:5100 --name demo-app-1 demo-app
```

Answer (score 2):

> I accessed through the binded port of the host server.

It's mean the application is running, and you're able to access using `curl localhost:8080`.

Now there are mainly two-issue if you're able to access the application after doing `ssh` to EC2 instance and verify the application responding on localhost of EC2.

- [Security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) not allowing connection on the desired port, allow `8080` and the check
- The [instance is in private subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html), you can verify the instance.